# Securing files stored on cdn

Tags: cdn

I am using 2 servers to complete my system, a cdn server used to store large protected documents, video, etc. And a .NET server for the website. I would like to know what is the best way to to have the cdn authenticate or validate a user before sending down a file for download.

Right now users log into the website and an Cookie is stored. Not sure how to go about protecting assets on cdn though. I don't want anonymous/visitors to use a link from their buddies to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask the CDN what authentication possibilities exist, and how to use them. This will  vary from provider to provider.

See e.g. the Security section in [Amazon S3's FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

Comment: OK, found out that they do Token Authorization. But tech/sales was not able to give me a clear explanation on how it would work.